# Can you use Google API to search for addresses without widget?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete, but don't see a way to just use their API to find those results with a custom widget. I see they have APIs without widgets, like places ("Joe's Pizza Shop"), but don't see the same for addresses which is hard to believe.

I want to use my existing autocomplete to avoid having a set of CSS for the usual autocomplete and then another set for this widget, and to avoid JSONP.

So is there no such API for addresses or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: are you talking about [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)?

Comment: No cause that would imply I know the address. I just want to send "100 Broadway" over along with an IP and get the right state's 100 Broadway. This works wonderfully with the widget... but the places API by itself requires you know lat/long already.

Comment: it seems like you'd have to do it yourself, i.e. infer the correct country with the assist of some locale-providing api. my guess is that the widget is simply bound to your google account and therefore have some preliminary data like your locale

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an API for that: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service

You can use `AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions` to get the same predictions as you'd get via the `Autocomplete` widget, and use it to implement your own UI.